# How do I make different types of input elements have the same width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-input

```css
.form-control, .custom-select {
    /* center form controls */
    display: inline-block;
    /* override Bootstrap's 100% width for form controls */
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<form action="/" method='post'>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select name="show_ID" required="required" class="custom-select">
        <option selected>Select something</option>
        <option value="Something1">Something 1</option>
        <option value="Something2">Something 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="something2" placeholder="Something 2" type="text"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

What's of interest here are the two **Bootstrap** elements `.form-control` and `.custom-select`. The HTML for each select box looks like this, although the option text in each is of different length:

[image]

As you can see, the form boxes in the custom-select boxes do not match each other, nor that of the form-control boxes, even though both have the exact same style specs.

I'm guessing what's happening is that the auto works on text boxes, since there is no pre-existing text to size the box off of, but that auto translates to "based on content" on the boxes that do have pre-existing text (i.e. custom-select).

The auto sizing of form-control works well on one HTML page where only form-control is used, but on another page I need to use both form-control and custom-select, and that's where the size becomes an issue.  I've tried setting a specific size for custom-select (eg. 65%), but even if I find a way to match the different box sizes (all custom-select boxes with the form-control boxes) on a desktop, on a mobile device they are off again, since auto means something different than, say, 65% on a cell phone.

How can I make all boxes the same size - both on desktop and mobile devices?

Comment: Sorry but can you clarify on what your issue is? Is your issue that CSS is not being implemented on two seperate pages, OR that it's not looking the same on desktop vs mobile?

Comment: The issue is that on the page where the two classes are mixed, the boxes are of different sizes. What I'm trying to accomplish is getting the boxes to be of the same size. I can kinda jimmy rig it by setting a specific percentage on custom-select, but that won't last once somebody uses a mobile device. Make sense?

Comment: So if I understood your further explanation, you are trying to make sure your layout will look the same, or at least be appropriate on different devices, right_

If so, you should look into responsive design and media queries, which allow you to resize wanted elements for certain screen size. 

Check this out : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Yeah that's already in my CSS stylesheet. Didn't help. And it doesn't help if I have to hard code .custom-select to a specific size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: It is working for me.

```
[Here You Go:][1]


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/whr4yc9v/1/
```

Comment: I believe this would make the width 100% on desktop, right? I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: You can give particular width. @thestacker